# Is it possible use different instance of UIMenuController for UITextField in Swift?

Tags: swift, uimenucontroller

According to [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller) we should use a singleton `UIMenuController` instance which is referred to the editing menu.
The problem is I want to show extra items in different situations. For instance, I want to just show "copy" item when keyboard is up. and show "copy" and "reply" when tapping on a tableview row.
When I add "reply" to the `UIMenuController` instance it is shown when tapping on `UITextField` too. therefore, I added these codes:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
var nonReplyMenuItems: [UIMenuItem] = []
        if let allMenuItems = UIMenuController.shared.menuItems {
            for menuItem in allMenuItems {
                if menuItem.title != "reply".localized {
                    nonReplyMenuItems.append(menuItem)
                }
            }
        }
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = nonReplyMenuItems
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

It fixed the problem in most situations, but not all.
when keyboard is up and tapping on a row in tableview "reply" will be added. Then when I tap on `UITextView` the reply will be shown there too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your scenario is like it:

tap on textfield ----> shows copy

tap on tableview ---> shows copy and reply

tab on textfield ----> shows copy and reply (you want only copy shows)

As I know the `textViewDidBeginEditing` calls when your text filed is not editing and you tap on that; So if you have two textfileds by switching on that method  calls every time but when you are switching between a text filed and another action base object your text field is editing and its state has not changed.

When you touch on tableview you must call `textfield.resignFirstResponder()` so when you tap on text field again the `textViewDidBeginEditing`  calls again, the problem of this is hiding keyboard; The better way I preferو is adding function to touch down of text field or on gesture to do what you write on `textViewDidBeginEditing` method